# use viewdata to perform inline styles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, css

Im populating viewdata with a bunch of css style properties.

```
<span style="font-size:50pt; font-family:"<%= ViewData["font"]%>";"><%= ViewData["UserCopy"]%> </span>
```

i want to be able to do something similar to the above. i.e use the style put into viewdata and use them on inline styles.

how can i do this?
thansk

Comment: What's not working with the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many double quotes. Try this:

```
<span style="font-size:50pt; font-family:<%= ViewData["font"]%>;">
    <%= Html.Encode((string)ViewData["UserCopy"]) %>
</span>
```

Comment: in the source that returns : <span style="font-size:50pt; font-family: ;">

Comment: Probably because your ViewData does not contain a `font` property. Make sure that the controller action rendering this view populates this property: `ViewData["font"] = "Times New Roman";`